# Mute command if you have a member role discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My mute command doesn't work even though I have all settings in channels and permissions. How do I override the Member role

```
@client.command(aliases=['m'])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def mute(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    muted_role = ctx.guild.get_role(muted role id)

    await member.add_roles(muted_role)
    await ctx.send(member.mention +" has been muted")
```

Answer (score -1):

You won't be able to override the role, but you can remove the role. Replace Member role with Muted role. And but member role permissions to view channel

```
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def mute(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    muted_role = ctx.guild.get_role(muted role id)
    member_role = ctx.guild.get_role(member role id)

    await member.add_roles(muted_role)
    await member.remove_roles(member_role)
    await ctx.send(member.mention +" has been muted")
```

and if you want to make an unmute command, just do the reverse

```
@client.command(aliases=['um'])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def unmute(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    muted_role = ctx.guild.get_role(muted role id)
    member_role = ctx.guild.get_role(member role id)

    await member.remove_roles(muted_role)
    await member.add_roles(member_role)
    await ctx.send(member.mention +" has been unmuted")
```

Comment: Yes, cause I was looking for this answer myself until I figured it out, and I wanted to post it here so if anyone else doesn't know that can know the answer @ŁukaszKwieciński. Besides it is and option in StackOverflow to answer your own question lol